# Seeking advice on using QGLWidget in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, qglwidget

I'm new here, and have a question about opengl in Qt4, which I've been learning over the last few months.

Particularly, I'm seeking advice on the best way to compose a scene in a good object-oriented fashion using the QGLWidget. I'd ideally like every item in my scene to be sub-classes of a super 'Entity' class. Then in my main QGLWidget I can sort the entities and render them accordingly.

I noticed though that certain openGL functions (like bindTexture) need to be called from the QGLWidget (or the widget's QGLContext). At the moment I'm passing a pointer to the QGLWidget that controls my main viewport to each entity and storing it so that I can gain access to those functions. Is this a good idea?

Any advice would be gratefully received, or even directions to good websites/books that might be of help. I've got the Blanchette/ Summerfield book but the OpenGL section is quite short and most of the examples on the Qt website are pretty simplistic.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Vime: You're building a scene graph, and there are a number of classical approaches for designing its object hierarchy. Check out "3D Game Engine Design," by Dave Eberly, for details on one such engine, and look at [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org) for another example.

Since only one GL context can be active at a time on a particular thread, consider storing the QGLWidget pointer as a static class member to save effort:

```
class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget {
    // ...
public:
    static inline MyGLWidget *GetActiveWidget() {
        return ms_activeWidget;
    }
protected:
    static __declspec(thread) MyGLWidget *ms_activeWidget = 0; // uses MSVC extension
    inline void SetActiveWidget() {
        ms_activeWidget = this;
    }
};

void MyGLWidget::paintGL() {
    SetActiveWidget();
    // ...
}
```

Then in your entity classes you can simply call `MyGLWidget::GetActiveWidget()` on the few occasions when you need to call QGLWidget member functions, and not need to copy a (probably invariant) pointer all over the place.

Comment: Thanks ChrisV, your static class member example makes an awful lot of sense and I've got that working.

I do have the Eberly book but haven't read it in detail, I've started looking at the section on Scene Graphs now though. How about OpenSceneGraph? I've heard a bit about that and have downloaded it to take a look, had any experience with it?

Comment: The one time I used OSG I wasn't too impressed, but that was a) several years ago and b) as part of a generally awful codebase. The object hierarchy design just didn't appeal to me. Since as I recall it tried to map a lot of OpenGL concepts directly into classes you can certainly take a look at it.

My advice for choosing a scene graph library, though? Look at the exporters. If you can't get your geometry into the library easily, it doesn't matter how well-designed the rest of the library is.

Answer (score 0):

You are building something that is usually called "scene graph". In our engine scene graph objects need no access to QGLWidget. It's enough if you create your OpenGL objects inside `void initializeGL()` and render everything inside `void paintGL()`.

There is a slightly higher level Qt/OpenGL example called Boxes. It can be found from `qt/demos/boxes` folder in Qt 4.6 installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That example is very handy, and I hadn't come across it before.

I've read a little about scene-graphs before, but never fully implemented one. I definitely need some simple frustrum culling so will investigate further but probably don't want to delve into anything too advanced. This is for a university project, so no end users other than myself and tutors. As long as it's relatively stable and I'm able to prove my other concepts, that's what counts.